# Multiple path additions to a variable in Linux (Bash)

Tags: linux, bash

I would like to know if my following implementation is correct or wrong.

I have a variable called `$MY_HUGE_PATH_VARIABLE`.

I need to enhance it by adding a few directories and all directories within those directories.

I set it up like this:

```
export MY_HUGE_PATH_VARIABLE=$PATH_1/version1/*\:\
$PATH_2/version4/*\:\
$PATH_n/versionn/*\
```

Is this correct. Does that `*` work when exporting paths? Are there any other issues with this piece of script. I am working on a Redhat Linux machine and my script in bash shell.

My aim is to include all the jar files within these folders for my Java compilation. 
My intention is to understand this stuff. the shell has not really thrown any errors to me as of yet and the script is part of a bigger set-up which I have not yet tested.

Comment: What you are trying to do can be dangerous. Maybe checkout http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17715/how-can-i-set-all-subdirectories-of-a-directory-into-path

Comment: I have .jar files within these paths, which i need to use for my Java code compilation. Thats why i am working on this sort of set-up

Comment: Ahh, this is somewhat of an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Update your question and explain WHY you want to do this. You can write a bash script to run your jar, and list all dependencies individually, or you can do something like `java -cp lib\*.jar;. myproject.MainClass` which seems to be what you

Answer (score 3):

EDIT:-
you dont need to specify * here, in linux it works like this:-

```
export MY_HUGE_PATH_VARIABLE=$MY_HUGE_PATH_VARIABLE$( find $PATH_1/version1/ $PATH_2/version4/ $PATH_n/versionn/ -type d -printf ":%p" )
```

Comment: Bash does not scan subdirectories of PATH variable recursively

Comment: I would be happy if you could give a small explanation of what happens as well. I am quite new to bash scripting

Comment: here `find`  will search for `-type` d(directories) and `printf` will print "%p"(files) along with `:` from the space separated paths you provided in `find` command.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following:

```
export MY_HUGE_PATH_VARIABLE=$(find $PATH_1/version1 $PATH_2/version4 $PATH_n/versionn -type d | tr '\n' ':')
```